# how to make orthographiccamera top view

Tags: typescript, three.js

[image]

I'm curious about how to set up a top view camera while considering the top left corner of the screen as (0,0).

If I increment the position.x of the mesh by 1, I would like it to appear as if it's moving to the left relative to the screen.

Conversely, if I decrement it by 1, it should move to the right.

How can I do this?

#### `vue3`, `nuxt`, `tailwind`

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { ref, h } from 'vue'

const width = 1100;
const height = 800;

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true,
    alpha: true,
    depth: true
});



// const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(47, width / height, 0.1, 1000);
const camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(0, width, 0, height, 0.1, 1000);
const scene = new THREE.Scene();

function createBox(): THREE.Mesh {

    const geo = new THREE.BoxGeometry(100, 50, 100, 34, 3, 1);
    geo.computeBoundingBox();
    geo.computeBoundingSphere();
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x000000 });
    const meshBox = new THREE.Mesh(geo, material);

    const wireframeGeometry = new THREE.WireframeGeometry(geo);
    const wireframeMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000, });
    const wireframeMesh = new THREE.LineSegments(wireframeGeometry, wireframeMaterial);

    const resultMesh = new THREE.Mesh();
    resultMesh.add(meshBox, wireframeMesh);

    return resultMesh;
}


(function () {

    camera.position.set(0, 0, 1000);
    // camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
    // camera.c


    // camera.rotateZ(3.14 * 0.5)
    // camera.rotateX(3.14 * 0.5)
    // camera.rotateY(0.5);

    // camera.up.set(0, 9950, 0)

    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();



    const exampleBox0 = createBox();
    exampleBox0.position.set(0, 0, 1);
    scene.add(exampleBox0);

    const exampleBox1 = createBox();
    exampleBox1.position.set(width*0.5, height*0.5, 50);
    scene.add(exampleBox1);

    const exampleBox2 = createBox();
    exampleBox2.position.set(width, height, 50);
    scene.add(exampleBox2);

    // 애니메이션 루프
    const animate = () => {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);


        exampleBox1.rotation.x += 0.01;
        // exampleBox1.rotation.y += 0.001;


        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    };
    animate();

})();












const body = ref<HTMLElement>();
onMounted(() => {
    const selfBody = body.value!;
    renderer.setSize(width, height, true);
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    selfBody.appendChild(renderer.domElement);


});

</script>

<template>
    <section ref="body" class="relative pt-[158px] mx-auto w-max">

    </section>
</template>
```

Comment: There is no point in adding tags to the title of the question.